# JS and JQuery Audio Volume Does Not Initialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

The Audio player loads and initializes, but the controls disappear once I pass the third song (see `>= 3` test). I'm not certain if that's an incredible coincidence but it seems likely I have broken something. Why do the audio controls vanish?

Also, the volume controls do not initialize. Does anyone know why?

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    if(number >= 3) {
        document.getElementById("audio").innerHTML = "<audio id='vid' src='remix.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' autoplay='true' loop='true'></audio>";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("audio").innerHTML = "<audio id='vid' src='lose.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' autoplay='true' loop='true'></audio>";
    }
};
(function(){
    var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
    vid.volume = 0.2;
    });
</script>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#vid").prop('volume', 0.2);
    window.setVolume = function(bgAudio,vol) {
        sounds[bgAudio].volume = 0.33;
    }
});
</script>
<div id="audio">

</div>
```

Comment: I tried to improve the English of your question, and I removed the extraneous background and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to replace the whole `audio` tag. Just change the `src` attribute:

```
<audio id='vid' src='remix.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' autoplay='true' loop='true'></audio>
```

...

```
$('#vid').attr('src', 'remix.mp3');
```

**EDIT**

Your code is a mess, I've tried to refactor it a bit:

```js
(function() {
  var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  var player = $('#vid');
  player.attr('src', number >= 3 ? 'remix.mp3' : 'lose.mp3');
  player.prop('volume', '0.2');
  player[0].play(); //run the audio track
  //not sure about this function
  window.setVolume = function(bgAudio, vol) {
    sounds[bgAudio].volume = vol;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id='vid' src='' type='audio/mpeg' loop='true'></audio>
```

And check mp3 file names and location.